# AWS Amplify: How can I sync data between each devices without stored in DynamoDB?

Tags: react-native, real-time, aws-appsync, datastore, aws-amplify

As the title suggested, we know when `DataStore.save()` performed, data would be transfer to the DynamoDB and already to sync to every client. So, the data will be store there.
Now I would like to sync only new data to other clients, after that, it will be clear in the DynamoDB. Users use data store locally in your device and when they delete them, bum, it disappears forever.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to clear DynamoDB after it's synced? Or you want to duplicate the data locally? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I want to clear DynamoDB after it's synced. And client uses data stored locally. Amplify likes a bridge, just sync data without keeping data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's solution after trying: DynamoDB Time to Live (TTL). Automatically delete items by configuration.